# Python - optimizing code ( looping through arrays )

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays, A and B. Based on a function, I create a subset C from A and a subset D from B. Now, I want to join them together ( I want to keep those items that are in C and D with the same index in A and B).

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20])
B = np.array([20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1])
C = np.array([3,7,13])
D = np.array([18,8])

fvl1 = list()
fvl2 = list()


for i in C:
    index = np.where(A == i)
    if B[index] in D:
        fvl1.append(A[index])
        fvl2.append(B[index])

print(fvl1)
print(fvl2)

Output:
[array([3]), array([13])]
[array([18]), array([8])]
```

This is what I've done until now, but it's really slow. Is there any way to optimize this for it to go faster?

LE: You can see that the element 3 in A has the same index as element 18 in B(index = 3), same with element 13 from A and 8 from B.

Comment: Have you tried using sets instead of lists?

Comment: MCVE please....

Comment: edited example now

Comment: Is `A` always sorted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`np.ind1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) or [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html#numpy.isin):

> Returns a boolean array of the same shape as element that is True
>   where an element of element is in test_elements and False otherwise.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20])
>>> B = np.array([20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1])
>>> C = np.array([3,7,13])
>>> D = np.array([18,8])
>>> np.in1d(A, C) & np.in1d(B, D)
array([False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> indices = np.isin(A, C) & np.isin(B, D)
>>> A[indices]
array([ 3, 13])
>>> B[indices]
array([18,  8])
```

It's not clear if `C` and `D` are converted to sets, but I suppose it will be faster than your current code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I interpreted your question correctly, but a combination of zip and list comprehension might be what you're after.

```
fv = [(a, b) for (a, b) in zip(A, B)
      if <condition for first list>
      and <condition for second list>]

fv1 = [t[0] for t in fv]
fv2 = [t[1] for t in fv]
```

zip joins your lists together into a list of tuples.

```
list(zip([1, 2, 3],['a','b','c'])) == [(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c')]
```

You can then filter which outputs you want with conditions in your list comprehension.  For example:

```
fv = [(a, b) for (a, b) in zip(range(10),'abcdefghijklmnop') 
      if a%2 
      and b>'d']
[(5, 'f'), (7, 'h'), (9, 'j')]
```

Your case can actually be done as a one liner:

```
fv1, fv2 = zip(*((a, b) for (a, b) in zip(A, B) if a in C and b in D))
fv1 #(3, 13)
fv2 #(18, 8)
```